# DockerException: Error while fetching server API version - docker SDK for python package

Tags: python, docker

I read though all the posts out there, but couldn't find a solution.

My Setup:

- M1 Mac
- Orbstack

I want to execute the following inside my docker container:

```
import docker

client = docker.from_env()
```

However I run into the (known):

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspaces/StatisticalArbitrage/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    client = docker.from_env()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/docker/client.py", line 94, in from_env
    return cls(
           ^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/docker/client.py", line 45, in __init__
    self.api = APIClient(*args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 197, in __init__
    self._version = self._retrieve_server_version()
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 220, in _retrieve_server_version
    raise DockerException(
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
```

See the details of my docker on M1 Mac below.

- Docker version

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:           25.0.3
 API version:       1.44
 Go version:        go1.21.6
 Git commit:        4debf41
 Built:             Tue Feb  6 21:13:26 2024
 OS/Arch:           darwin/arm64
 Context:           orbstack

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          25.0.3
  API version:      1.44 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.21.6
  Git commit:       f417435
  Built:            Tue Feb  6 21:14:35 2024
  OS/Arch:          linux/arm64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.7.13
  GitCommit:        7c3aca7a610df76212171d200ca3811ff6096eb8
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.12
  GitCommit:        51d5e94601ceffbbd85688df1c928ecccbfa4685
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

- Docker info

```
$ docker info
Client:
 Version:    25.0.3
 Context:    orbstack
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.12.1
    Path:     /Users/simonleiner/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v2.23.3
    Path:     /Users/simonleiner/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose
WARNING: Plugin "/Users/simonleiner/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-dev" is not valid: failed to fetch metadata: fork/exec /Users/simonleiner/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-dev: no such file or directory
WARNING: Plugin "/Users/simonleiner/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-extension" is not valid: failed to fetch metadata: fork/exec /Users/simonleiner/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-extension: no such file or directory
WARNING: Plugin "/Users/simonleiner/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-init" is not valid: failed to fetch metadata: fork/exec /Users/simonleiner/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-init: no such file or directory
WARNING: Plugin "/Users/simonleiner/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-sbom" is not valid: failed to fetch metadata: fork/exec /Users/simonleiner/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-sbom: no such file or directory
WARNING: Plugin "/Users/simonleiner/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-scan" is not valid: failed to fetch metadata: fork/exec /Users/simonleiner/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-scan: no such file or directory
WARNING: Plugin "/Users/simonleiner/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-scout" is not valid: failed to fetch metadata: fork/exec /Users/simonleiner/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-scout: no such file or directory

Server:
 Containers: 2
  Running: 1
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 1
 Images: 6
 Server Version: 25.0.3
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: btrfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Using metacopy: false
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 2
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 7c3aca7a610df76212171d200ca3811ff6096eb8
 runc version: 51d5e94601ceffbbd85688df1c928ecccbfa4685
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: builtin
  cgroupns
 Kernel Version: 6.5.13-orbstack-00122-g57b8027e2387
 Operating System: OrbStack
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: aarch64
 CPUs: 8
 Total Memory: 2.513GiB
 Name: orbstack
 ID: 98b73600-a3c5-4e6f-90d2-8a3f38648f73
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
 Product License: Community Engine
```

- Docker context

```
$ docker context ls
NAME            DESCRIPTION                               DOCKER ENDPOINT                                       ERROR
default         Current DOCKER_HOST based configuration   unix:///var/run/docker.sock                           
desktop-linux   Docker Desktop                            unix:///Users/simonleiner/.docker/run/docker.sock     
orbstack *      OrbStack                                  unix:///Users/simonleiner/.orbstack/run/docker.sock
```

Edit:

- Running

  pip install docker
  returns:
  Requirement already satisfied: docker in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (7.0.0)
  Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=14.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from docker) (23.2)
  Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.26.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from docker) (2.31.0)
  Requirement already satisfied: urllib3>=1.26.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from docker) (2.2.1)
  Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from requests>=2.26.0->docker) (3.3.2)
  Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from requests>=2.26.0->docker) (3.6)
  Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from requests>=2.26.0->docker) (2024.2.2)

Comment: How did you install docker? The error message says `docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were confused between Orbstack and docker SDK.

#### Orbstack

Orbstack is a 3rd-party alternative to Docker Desktop (macOS only), which means you can run docker containers, build images, etc.

#### docker SDK for python

docker SDK as python package for interacting with Docker daemon

If I understand from your question you're trying to interact with Docker daemon from your python code.
See the quote below from Docker SDK for python [docs](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client.html).

> To communicate with the Docker daemon, you first need to instantiate a client. The easiest way to do that is by calling the function from_env(). It can also be configured manually by instantiating a DockerClient class

So, if you need to run python to work with Docker daemon, then install the docker package using `pip`.

```
$ pip install docker
Collecting docker
  Using cached docker-7.0.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.5 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=14.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from docker) (23.2)
Collecting requests>=2.26.0 (from docker)
...
...
Successfully installed docker-7.0.0 requests-2.31.0 urllib3-2.2.1

$ python
>>> import docker
>>> client = docker.from_env()
```

Comment: Thanks for your clarifications. I edited the question, because I already pip installed docker with success, however the error still persits... . Maybe it can't find the "pip installed docker". I am grateful for any Help!!

Comment: Your welcome, what do you see if you run pip list

Comment: "docker                    7.0.0" Version is shown. Maybe its something with orbstack, guess I wil change to docker desktop again, as there are more docs available.